# Delete outdated SVN tags

Tags: svn, tags

What is the best practice for removing old, outdated tags in svn? Is there any reason to keep them around, since I should be able to retrieve them from svn's history if needed?

Answer (score 1):

Do whatever works best for you. If created properly, the tags are taking up negligible disk space, and deleting them won't release that space (technically, it'll consume more, because you'll have to record the revision(s) where the delete happened).

I move my tags into subdirectories sorted by year to keep things tidier.